# Integration Salesforce and Twilio

Tags: error, twilio

I am using Salesforce and Twilio API, but when I send a SMS message with more than 160 characters, I receive the message below.

TwilioRestException:[errorCode=21605, message=The message body exceeds the 160 character limit., moreInfo=https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21605, status=400]: Script-thrown exception

I looked the error page showed in the error message, but I didn´t figure out what I have to change in the API call to allow bigger messages to be sent. To install Twilio in my Salesforce org, I used this package: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

This is as per the old Twilio endpoint used in the wrapper Salesforce library. Internally it uses the `/SMS/Messages` endpoint which limits max size to 160 characters and is now deprecated. The error you receive in this case is expected and listed [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/reference).

You should now be using the new /Messages endpoint described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) which allows up to 1600 characters.